# async value not returned after lock released while using sqlite-net in winrt app

Tags: c#, locking, async-await, sqlite-net

I recently encountered this very strange problem.
Initially I have this block of code

```
public async Task<string> Fetch(string module, string input)
{
    if (module != this._moduleName)
    {
        return null;
    }
    try
    {
        var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(_dbPath);
        ResponsePage storedResponse = new ResponsePage();

        Action<SQLiteConnection> trans = connect =>
            {
                storedResponse = connect.Get<ResponsePage>(input);
            };
        await db.RunInTransactionAsync(trans);
        string storedResponseString = storedResponse.Response;
        return storedResponseString;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However control will never be handed back to my code after the transaction finishes running. I traced the program and it seems that after the lock is release, the flow of program stops. Then I switched to using the GetAsync method from SQLiteAsyncConnection class. Basically it did the same thing so I was still blocked at await. Then I removed the async calls and used the synchronous api like below:

```
public async Task<string> Fetch(string module, string input)
{
    if (module != this._moduleName)
    {
        return null;
    }
    try
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
        ResponsePage storedResponse = new ResponsePage();
        lock (_dbLock)
        {
            storedResponse = db.Get<ResponsePage>(input);
        }
        string storedResponseString = storedResponse.Response;
        return storedResponseString;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Only then can the logic flows back to my code. However I can't figure out why is this so.
Another problem is that for this kind of simple query is there any gain in terms of query time if I use aysnc api instead of sync api? If not I'll stick to the sync version then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely calling `Result` (or `Wait`) further up the call stack from `Fetch`. This will cause a deadlock, as I explain [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

For your second question, there is some overhead from `async`, so for extremely fast asynchronous operations, the synchronous version will be faster. There is no way to tell whether this is the case in your code unless you do profiling.

Comment: Thank you! I found that's exactly what caused my problem and your problem helped me solve it. I also gained better understanding of using async methods.